# EPPlus - Error when copying worksheet with conditional formatting

Tags: .net, epplus, conditional-formatting, worksheet

I'm using **EPPlus 4.1**, last stable version (Also tried 4.5.0.1-beta with same result).

I'm trying to merge several excel files (created using EPPlus), into single excel file with multiple worksheets. Some of worksheets may contain conditional formatting, which I set as below:

```
'Using columnCells As ExcelRange = workSheetData.Cells(headerLevels + 2, c + 1, workSheetData.Dimension.End.Row + 1, c + 1) 'headerLevels + 2
'    Dim cond1 = columnCells.ConditionalFormatting.AddGreaterThan()
'    cond1.Formula = "0.0"
'    cond1.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.Color = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#CBDEB7") 'light green

'    Dim cond2 = columnCells.ConditionalFormatting.AddLessThan()
'    cond2.Formula = "0.0"
'    cond2.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.Color = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#F1CDB1") 'light red
'End Using

Dim cfAddress As New ExcelAddress(headerLevels + 2, c + 1, workSheetData.Dimension.End.Row + 1, c + 1)
Dim cfRule1 = workSheetData.ConditionalFormatting.AddGreaterThan(cfAddress)
cfRule1.Formula = "0.0"
cfRule1.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.Color = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#CBDEB7") 'light green

Dim cfRule2 = workSheetData.ConditionalFormatting.AddLessThan(cfAddress)
cfRule2.Formula = "0.0"
cfRule2.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.Color = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#F1CDB1") 'light red
```

Both ways produce same result and work fine for the source files.

Then, I'm merging these files by copying worksheets into new file as below

```
Dim fileInfoMaster As New System.IO.FileInfo(filePath)
Using _pckMaster As New ExcelPackage(fileInfoMaster)

    For i As Integer = 0 To masterWorkbookParams.ListOfFileNames.Count() - 1
        filePath = folderPath & masterWorkbookParams.ListOfFileNames(i) & ".xlsx"
        If System.IO.File.Exists(filePath) Then
            Dim fileInfo As New System.IO.FileInfo(filePath)
            Using _pck As New ExcelPackage(fileInfo)

                Dim NewWorksheet As ExcelWorksheet = _pckMaster.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(masterWorkbookParams.ListOfSheetNames(i), _pck.Workbook.Worksheets(1))

            End Using
        End If
    Next i

    _pckMaster.Save()
End Using
```

The line `_pckMaster.Save()` produces an error.
When I inspected in the debugger the worksheet of source file and worksheet of destination file before that line executed, I saw the following picture:

Source file:

[image: screenshot]

Destination file:

[image: screenshot]

The ConditionalFormatting node in the worksheet has an exception after we add a copy to the new file. If the source file does not have any conditional formatting, adding a copy of worsheet from one workbook to a new workbook and saving that file work as expected.

Did anyone have the same issue? Is it a bug? or I'm doing something wrong here?

> ConditionalFormatting '(New System.Linq.SystemCore_EnumerableDebugView(Of OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorksheet)(_pckMaster.Workbook.Worksheets).Items(1)).ConditionalFormatting' threw an exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException'  OfficeOpenXml.ConditionalFormatting.ExcelConditionalFormattingCollection {System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException}

StackTrace

- System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException(ExceptionArgument argument, ExceptionResource resource)
- OfficeOpenXml.ConditionalFormatting.ExcelConditionalFormattingRule..ctor(eExcelConditionalFormattingRuleType type, ExcelAddress address, Int32 priority, ExcelWorksheet worksheet, XmlNode itemElementNode, XmlNamespaceManager namespaceManager)
- OfficeOpenXml.ConditionalFormatting.ExcelConditionalFormattingGreaterThan..ctor(ExcelAddress address, Int32 priority, ExcelWorksheet worksheet, XmlNode itemElementNode, XmlNamespaceManager namespaceManager)
- OfficeOpenXml.ConditionalFormatting.ExcelConditionalFormattingRuleFactory.Create(eExcelConditionalFormattingRuleType type, ExcelAddress address, Int32 priority, ExcelWorksheet worksheet, XmlNode itemElementNode)
- OfficeOpenXml.ConditionalFormatting.ExcelConditionalFormattingCollection..ctor(ExcelWorksheet worksheet)
- OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorksheet.get_ConditionalFormatting()

Comment: You might want to check that you are not copying duplicated conditional formatting rules

Comment: @YahyaHussein Yes, I also tried to set conditional formatting for single cell with only one conditional rule. The result is the same, after this sheet is copied to a new workbook, there is an error on saving that file.

Comment: @AlexeyPolyanichko Have you found a solution? I am having the same issue now and can't seem to find a way to fix it.

Comment: @Kevin No, the problem is still there(

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, I have created a correction for this in the latest EPPlus version. See Issue #464 on Github. Also mentioned as issue #266.